# save search keywords to text file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am customizing the functionality of chrome extension (Google Dictionary) where I want to save each word I look up to a text file by pressing a button. The current functionality does the following code is to save each word the user types in a separate file and ask where to save the file. But I want to append each word to a permanent, say log file. In PHP this would be extremely easy however in javascript this is problematic because of clientside scripting functionality. I found a [solution](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#filewriter) for this but this is really complicated and I don't know how to implement that. any other solutions/suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <input type="text" id="inputTextToSave"><button id="define-btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Define" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Define</button>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 function saveTextAsFile()
    {
var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = "log.txt";
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";

downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
downloadLink.click();
    }
 </script>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Html 5 web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). Infact it works on all major browsers. Just in case u want to expand ur app to other browsers as well. You can then write the read data from storage to a file. [Chrome Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion: Instead of doing that, why don't you save it in localStorage (or storage depending on your file size).

Then in the background page of your extension, provide an option to download these words as a file using regular file dialog box.

Comment: but is it possible to retrieve the previous data with localStorage after I close the browser or shutdown the computer ?

Comment: of course!! It is called storage because it is persistent storage - data goes to disk.

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone's interested in script solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <input type="text" id="inputTextToSave"><button id="define-btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Define" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Define</button>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textToWriteOld = localStorage.getItem("inputTextStorage");
    if(textToWriteOld === null) textToWriteOld = "";
    localStorage.setItem("inputTextStorage", textToWriteOld + "\n" + textToWrite);
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([localStorage.getItem("inputTextStorage")], {type:'text/plain'});


    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = "log.txt";
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.click();
}
</script>
</html>
```

Any other improvements would be appreciated as well.